# not recognized as a supported file format ECW gdal api

Tags: c++, dictionary, gdal, qgis

I'm trying to use **ECW files** in my application. I've built **GDAL Library** whit this command:

```
./configure --with-ecw:/usr/local/hexagon
```

after completion of build process, when I Entered:

```
gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW
```

I got:

```
ECW -raster- (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.5)
JP2ECW -raster,vector- (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.5)
```

also when I've used

```
gdalinfo map.ecw
```

it returns all metadata of ECW files.
but when I compile my C++ program, it returns:

> Error:  GDAL Dataset returned null from read

> ERROR 4: `map.ecw' not recognized as a supported file format.

Dose anyone know why I can't use **ECW files in C++ program**?

By the way, I use
**Cmake**
,**GDAL 3.3.0**
,**Erdas-ECW SDK 5.5 hexagon**
for building the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. This problem occurs if the gdal_bin binary package is installed before creating GDAL.
Just make sure gdal_bin is deleted before installing the version you created.